# Solving cycles - Permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I’m trying to get $(16523)$ using $(132)$ and $(13456)$ but I’m not able to. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

[Check Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=perm+%281+3+4+5+6%29%5E3%281+3+2%29%281+3+4+5+6%29)

$$(1 6 5 2 3) = (1 3 4 5 6)^3(1 3 2)(1 3 4 5 6)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think these are too tedious to solve mechanically!